# Why does Unity Eventsystem lag on first touch?

Tags: unity, unityscript

Hi I am making a very simple simple platformer game for android devices. I am using Unity's event system for player movement. The problem is when I touched the button first time there is a lag (hiccup) after then everything is ok. I have profiled my game there is a spike in EventSystem Update method.

here is the simplified code,

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D)) ]   
[RequireComponent (typeof(BoxCollider2D)) ]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {


public float movementSpeed = 5f;
public float jumpForce = 5f;
public float distanceToGround = 0.2f;
public LayerMask staticCollider;
public playerState state;

private Rigidbody2D rBody;
public Transform leftmost;
public Transform rightmost;

Collider2D[] platforms = new Collider2D[2];
public int hrInput = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ( ) {
    rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

}


//FixedUpdate is framerate independent, and therefore completely unrelated to your framerate

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    state.grounded = isGrounded ();


    if (hrInput > 0) {
        MOVE_RIGHT ();
    }
    else if (hrInput < 0) {
        MOVE_LEFT ();
    } else {
        STOP_MOVE ();

    }

}

public bool isGrounded(){
    print ("ground");
    if (Physics2D.OverlapAreaNonAlloc (leftmost.position, rightmost.position, platforms, staticCollider) > 0) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}


public void setHrInput (int h ) {
//    print (h);

    hrInput = h;
}

public void JUMP(){
    if(state.grounded){
        state.onAir = true;
      //  rBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        rBody.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
}

public void MOVE_LEFT(){
    rBody.velocity = new Vector2 (-1 * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, rBody.velocity.y);
}

public void MOVE_RIGHT(){
    rBody.velocity = new Vector2(1 * movementSpeed*Time.deltaTime, rBody.velocity.y);
}

public void STOP_MOVE(){
    rBody.velocity = new Vector2(0,rBody.velocity.y);
    }

} // end
```

Here is the profiler Image.

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: That's actually a good question. I always experience the same thing, no matter how big the game is o.O.

Comment: Which button lags when you first press it, all of them or just one or does the game just lag at first touch input irrelevant of the button? Also, it'd help to see the profiler's lag spike and to see which events are using how much time during that frame.

Comment: all of them, ok I am uploading the profiler screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot isn't particularly helpful. You're looking at pretty solid 100 fps there.  That's fast.  The underlined portion of 4.6 kb is garbage collection and that's pretty minimal.

Comment: the garbage collection is minimal but I am still having the hiccup problem when I run the game on mobile device but in PC the game is running smoothly.

Comment: It doesn't help that your code has nothing to do with the Event System or the problem you are trying to solve. Can you modify your example to not include anything that's not related to the "first touch" problem?

Comment: What does your UI content look like? Are there a lot of GraphicRaycasters on it? Did you try removing them from canvases that you don't interact with? The most common issue I can think of is that by default all of the generated Canvases get one, and on first interaction it probably spends some time setting up data for later efficient raycasts. But that's an assumption, I haven't looked at the actual implementation in a while.

Comment: the UI is very simple two button for move left and right and another button for jump. I had not remove or attach anything on canvas. just created an UI canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Touch input is always a bit of a PITA (I actually recommend the InControl package / not affiliated in anyway) regardless, I believe that the main problem you're experiencing is due to your check for input in FixedUpdate. Input should be checked in Update, FixedUpdate is for updating physic bodies. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: The notion that input should be checked only in Update is also questionable. The Unity docs do mention it, but their description doesn't match the behaviour in Unity 4.6+ (the earliest I've tested), where up-to-date input is available as early as FixedUpdate. If you're using input to generate physics responses, processing it in FixedUpdate can actually remove a frame of latency, relative to doing so in Update. It just requires extra care to avoid double-handling or skipping inputs. In any case, checking an int variable in FixedUpdate will not be the cause of the stall described in the question

Comment: Speaking from actual experience. Checking for Input in FixedUpdate will cause latency issues / dropped inputs and undesired behaviour. To my knowledge (since Unity 3.2 / 3.3) FixedUpdate was designed specifically for for the Physics System. Check for Input in Update, not FixedUpdate. My answer stands. Care to make your comments an Answer?